# LoopBack "group by" ability with mySQL?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm new to `LoopBack`, and I seem to be missing something.
I've heard so much about `StrongLoop` and `LoopBack`, I find it hard to believe this doesn't exist.

My case:
I'm looking to count the amount of events with each different severity.

A table for example:

> **EventID | Severity**
>
> 1 | 2
>
> 2 | 2
>
> 3 | 4
>
> 4 | 3
>
> 5 | 3
>
> 6 | 5
>
> 7 | 1
>
> 8 | 2

Now I want to count the amount of events and group them by severity, so I get something like this JSON back:

```
{1:1, 2:3, 3:2, 4:1, 5:1} *(severity:count)*
```

With SQL it's quite simple, just use `"SELECT severity, count(severity) FROM events GROUP BY severity"`.

I have researched this for a while, and still can't believe this simple thing can't be done with `LoopBack`!

Any solution? Or maybe an article to point me to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Well Loopback ORM as of this moment doesn't have support for it completely but you can always use the MySQL driver directly:

```
YourModel.dataSource.connector.query('SELECT severity, count(severity) FROM events GROUP BY severity', (err, results) => {
   //...
});
```

But if you want to be database agnostic, you can do it in Javascript with Lodash:

```
YourModel.find({ fields: 'severity' }).then(rows => {
  const results = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(rows, severity), 'length');
  //...
});
```